# String Division in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings that all follow a format of parts of the name divided by underscores. Here is the format:

`string="somethingX_somethingY_one_two"`

What I want to know how to do it extract "one_two" from each string in the list and rebuild the list so that each entry only has `"somethingX_somethingY"`. I know that in C, there is a strtok function that is useful for splitting into tokens, but I'm not sure if there is a method like that or a strategy to get that same effect in Python. Help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use split and a list comprehension:

```
l = ['_'.join(s.split('_')[:2]) for s in l]
```

Comment: @killown: you have applied this to the string, instead of to a list of strings. I think I saw a couple other places where you looked back over questions and claimed they didn't work -- maybe try reading the questions a bit more thoroughly first =)?

Comment: @katrielalex: it fails if the string is "somethingX_one_two_somethingY"

Comment: @killown: It also fails if the string is `"Elephants."` You can't assume you know the problem; you need to use the specification that the OP gave.

Comment: yes, i am using it: "What I want to know how to do it extract "one_two from each string"

Answer (score 3):

If you're literally trying to remove "_one_two" from the end of the strings, then you can do this:

```
tail_len = len("_one_two")
strs = [s[:-tail_len] for s in strs]
```

If you want to remove the last two underscore-separated components, then you can do this:

```
strs = ["_".join(s.split("_")[:-2]) for s in strs]
```

If neither of these is what you want, then let update the question with more details.

Comment: your code fails if string is  "somethingX_one_two_somethingY"

Comment: @killown: you are right.  I gave two interpretations of the under-specified problems.  I'm not willing to make many more guesses what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you're asking for.

```
s = "somethingX_somethingY_one_two"
splitted = s.split( "_" )
splitted = [ x for x in splitted if "something" in x ]
print "_".join( splitted )
```